# Xcode cannot launch the app because the device is locked

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am getting this error when I run the app in an actual device even the device is unlocked.

[image]

I tried disconnecting and connecting the device, rebooting the device, restart Xcode and clean the project but every time I am getting this error. I am using XCode 10.2 on macOS 10.14.4
I didn't find solutions on SO, so posting a question here.

**Edit:** This problem arise eveytime when I start the system and run project for the first time.

Comment: Unpair the device and again pair it.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Thanks but Unpair and pairing device doesn't working in my case, I know this can be a solution.

Comment: Then I think you need to delete the symbol files for your device from your PC and then try again.

Comment: In your iPhone Device Go to Setting > Developer > click in “Clear Trusted Computer” Type the passcode required, then Unpair and pairing device.

Comment: Found solutions for this:
Unpaired device, restart Xcode 2-3 times, restart the device and paired again and keep it unlocked when running the project. Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 22):

Generally, unpair and repair will resolve the issue

[image]

[image]

Then try repair again

Answer (score 8):

Is there anything like by chance you tapped not -

> "**Trust This Computer**" ?

This will prevent it from communicating with xcode even if the device is unlocked.

Follow a support [Documentation from Apple](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5868):

**Workaround**

- Disconnect your device from your Computer and close your Xcode project.
- On your iphone go to Settings > General > Reset, then press Reset
  Location & Privacy
- connect your device back into your Macbook, and on the iPhone you will
  be prompted to trust the Macbook. Tap trust.
- Now reopen Xcode and rebuild the project.
- The iPhone locked error should disappear.

**Another Workaround works for people**

- unplug your iPhone
- quit Xcode completely
- open xcode Project
- plug in your iPhone
- build and run

**Another Workaround**

- Go to Window -> Devices & Simulators. Right click on your iPhone &
  unpair it.
- Disconnect from cable & reconnect.
- Wait for it & let Xcode detect you iPhone.
- Run your project.
- Make sure you TRUST on your iOS device and enter any passcode.

Answer (score -1):

Just replug the cable from iphone to mac and it will works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).